# 2005 Suzuki katana 600 carburetors not delivering fuel

Tags: engine, motorcycle, fuel-system, suzuki, carburetor

I have a 2005 katana that was given to me I cleaned the carbs and it ran ok. I was riding it for a few weeks then overshot a corner and crashed, the damage wasn’t too bad scratched some plastics and cracked the valve cover, I fixed all that and decided to do a better job at cleaning the carbs. I put the carburetors back on after cleaned then well, with a water bottle gas tank I plugged off the vac lines on 1 and 4 carbs and I made sure that there was fuel in the bowls. But for some reason the motor is not sucking in the fuel. It’ll start up if I spray starter fluid in it and if I blow into the carb vent tubes that hang over the air cleaner it will start like that as well does Amy know what’s wrong thanks.

Comment: Did you dismantle the carbs to clean them?

Comment: This engine has 4 carbs I believe.   When you blow into the vent tubes are you blowing into the fuel float chambers?  If so, is it 1 pipe for all or are there 4 pipes?

Comment: Is the throttle operating correctly?

Comment: Carburetors are not diy friendly to anyone unfamiliar with their operation. Downdraft and side draft carbs operate differently from each other. Perhaps looking into a carb manual for your Katana 600 can help. Venturi theory is the basis of most naturally aspirated carburetors.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Katana 600, but here's some suggestions - does it have an electric fuel pump? Many modern motorbikes have these as the tank can be lower than the carbs so check to see that it operates. Check that the vent in the fuel cap is not blocked. the fuel tap (if it has one) might be vacuum operated - it needs the engine running to let fuel flow. These would usually have a 'prime' position to bypass the valve. All your floats got jammed due to the crash. Usually a sharp tap with the butt end of a screwdriver shakes them back into place.